# Scroll not working for dropdown selection in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

When I use  keyboard for dropdown selection, scroll doesn't move up and down,so I am not able to see which one is selected right now. How to move scroll up and down when keyboard is pressed up and down. My sample code is as following:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

class GUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [(10), (20), (30), (40), (50), (60), (70), (80), (90), (100)]
        self.work_order_currrent_selection_index = 0

    def run(self):
        layout = [[sg.Listbox(values=self.data, size=(35, 3), enable_events=True, key='selected_key')]]
        # Create the Window
        self.testWindow = sg.Window('Test', return_keyboard_events=True).Layout(layout).Finalize()
        self.testWindow.Maximize()
        self.testWindow.Element('selected_key').Update(set_to_index=0) 
        # Event Loop to process "events"
        while True:
            event, values = self.testWindow.Read()
            if event in('Up:111', '16777235'):
                if(hasattr(self, 'testWindow')):
                    self.work_order_currrent_selection_index = (self.work_order_currrent_selection_index - 1) % len(self.data)
                    self.testWindow.Element('selected_key').Update(set_to_index=self.work_order_currrent_selection_index) 
            elif event in ('Down:116',' 16777237'):
                if(hasattr(self, 'testWindow')):
                    self.work_order_currrent_selection_index = (self.work_order_currrent_selection_index + 1) % len(self.data)
                    self.testWindow.Element('selected_key').Update(set_to_index=self.work_order_currrent_selection_index)  

        self.testWindow.Close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = GUI()
    app.run()
```

When application launch first time I just able to see three dropdown as,
[image]

I pressed down arrow key then selection go down one by one like that,

[image]

[image]

But after selection of 30, on the down key press selection move to next one like 40, 50.. except scrolling, so I am not able to see which one is selected now.
Is there any way to move selection along with scrolling?

[image]

See the fourth image, here selection moved to 40 but scroll not moved down. Same issue with up key pressed.

Comment: Same thing work well when I first selection done by clicking mouse then move up or down with keyboard.

Comment: I assume you understood the answer and what you were missing which was the scroll_to_index parameter.  You don't need to use a class for the code I see so far.  It just means typing an extra "self." in front of everything :-)  A function would work just as well best I can tell, but I don't know where this code fits overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will get you a little closer to what you're looking for

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

class GUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [(10), (20), (30), (40), (50), (60), (70), (80), (90), (100)]
        self.work_order_currrent_selection_index = 0

    def run(self):
        layout = [[sg.Listbox(values=self.data, size=(35, 3), enable_events=True, key='selected_key')]]
        # Create the Window
        self.testWindow = sg.Window('Test', layout, return_keyboard_events=True, finalize=True)
        # self.testWindow.Maximize()
        self.testWindow.Element('selected_key').Update(set_to_index=0)
        # Event Loop to process "events"
        while True:
            event, values = self.testWindow.Read()
            if event is None:
                break
            if event.startswith('Up'):
                self.work_order_currrent_selection_index = (self.work_order_currrent_selection_index - 1) % len(self.data)
                self.testWindow['selected_key'].Update(set_to_index=self.work_order_currrent_selection_index,scroll_to_index=self.work_order_currrent_selection_index )
            elif event.startswith('Down'):
                self.work_order_currrent_selection_index = (self.work_order_currrent_selection_index + 1) % len(self.data)
                self.testWindow['selected_key'].Update(set_to_index=self.work_order_currrent_selection_index, scroll_to_index=self.work_order_currrent_selection_index)

        self.testWindow.Close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = GUI()
    app.run()
```